# Unable to print 2d Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

## I am trying to take input to 2d array and print it .

> I don't want to use ArrayList collection of Java Interfaces or any other libraries
>   I am having problem in printing  it on the console .The input is working well

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

class Triangle{
    public static int n;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, j, cases;
        int[][] values = new int[100][100];
        cases = in.nextInt();
        while(cases-- > 0){
            n = in.nextInt();
            int temp;
            for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
                for(j=0 ; j<=i ; j++){
                    values[i][j] = in.nextInt();
                }
            }    
        }
        large(values);
    }
    public static void large(int[][] arr){
        for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; i++){
            for(int j=i ; j<i ; j++){
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having?  The only problem I see at first glance is that you never tally the `sum` as you go along.

Comment: Oh! I forgot to remove sum. Just wanted to input and print 2d array in triangular form like a pyaramid

Answer (score 2):

Your problems start here:

```
public static void large(int[][] arr){
    for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; i++){
```

What makes you think that the last *n* entered by the user reflects the boundaries of your arrays?

In other words: you defined your array to be of size 100 x 100; and arrays themselves know their size; so you just go for

```
for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
```

And please note: you should consider to rework your "input" method as well. As of now, that code is **highly** confusing; looping style is strange; and as said: good protection against going beyond array limits ... looks differently than what you put down!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print all the array you need to start each index with 0, in you code you start your second loop with i, and you forgot to add each entry to the sum

```
      public static void large(int[][] arr){
    for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<i ; j++){
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
             sum+=arr[i][j];
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
   }
```